# How to capture header of file, then perform further text processing on original file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to capture the first 8 lines of the following file, then capture all fields where NPU # is equal to 7 or 3, and NPU core is equal to 1.

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:xxxxx#show controllers npu voq-usage interface all instance all location 0/0/CPU0
33144 Tue Jun  4 xxxx
33145 -------------------------------------------------------------------
33146 Node ID: 0/0/CPU0
33147 Intf         Intf     NPU NPU  PP   Sys   VOQ   Flow   VOQ    Port
33148 name         handle    #  core Port Port  base  base   port   speed
33149 (hex)                                     type
33150 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
33151 Hu0/0/2/1    210       0   1   21    21   1024   4152 local   100G
33152 Hu0/0/2/47   218       7   0    1   701   1032   4152 local   100G
33153 Hu0/0/2/46   220       7   0    5   705   1040   4216 local   100G
33154 Hu0/0/2/45   228       7   0    9   709   1048   4280 local   100G
33155 Hu0/0/2/44   230       3   1   17   717   1056   4152 local   100G
```

I'm able to do this with the following disparate awk commands:

```
awk 'NR<9' filename.txt
awk '($4==7||$4==3) && $5==1' filename.txt
```

Can I get some advice on how I might join these awk statement together? Or maybe even a bash-ism that would be more elegant to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: `awk 'NR<9 || (($4==7||$4==3) && $5==1)' file > newfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '(NR<9) || (($4~/^[73]$/) && ($5==1))' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a `||` operator and group the second condition:

```
awk 'NR<9 || (($4==7||$4==3) && $5==1)' filename.txt > newfilename.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/KMhFn1):

```
s="RP/0/RP0/CPU0:xxxxx#show controllers npu voq-usage interface all instance all location 0/0/CPU0
33144 Tue Jun  4 xxxx
33145 -------------------------------------------------------------------
33146 Node ID: 0/0/CPU0
33147 Intf         Intf     NPU NPU  PP   Sys   VOQ   Flow   VOQ    Port
33148 name         handle    #  core Port Port  base  base   port   speed
33149 (hex)                                     type
33150 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
33151 Hu0/0/2/1    210       0   1   21    21   1024   4152 local   100G
33152 Hu0/0/2/47   218       7   0    1   701   1032   4152 local   100G
33153 Hu0/0/2/46   220       7   0    5   705   1040   4216 local   100G
33154 Hu0/0/2/45   228       7   0    9   709   1048   4280 local   100G
33155 Hu0/0/2/44   230       3   1   17   717   1056   4152 local   100G"

awk 'NR<9 || (($4==7||$4==3) && $5==1)'  <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:xxxxx#show controllers npu voq-usage interface all instance all location 0/0/CPU0
33144 Tue Jun  4 xxxx
33145 -------------------------------------------------------------------
33146 Node ID: 0/0/CPU0
33147 Intf         Intf     NPU NPU  PP   Sys   VOQ   Flow   VOQ    Port
33148 name         handle    #  core Port Port  base  base   port   speed
33149 (hex)                                     type
33150 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
33155 Hu0/0/2/44   230       3   1   17   717   1056   4152 local   100G
```

Comment: While this is a good functional solution, I find that Ed's solution is more elegant. Cheers

Comment: @user And can you further enhance/adjust Ed's solution? If you had written you preferred a regex, I would provide a regex, with explanation and demos.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, will specify next time. Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try 1 more way.

```
awk 'NR<=9{print;next} ($4==7||$4==3) && $5==1'  Input_file
```

Comment: is there any benefit of using next in this case? I get the same result when using: awk 'NR<9{print} ($4==7||$4==3) && $5==1' file.txt

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1,8b;/^(\S+\s+){3}[37]\s+1\s/!d' file
```

Print lines 1 to 8 and any lines where the 4th field is either 3 or 7 and 5th field is 1.